# Unity3D - Why my object doesnt move every frame per second

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im struggling with very weird and propably simple problem,I have created a robot and his task is to move towards target I mean Im using Vector3.MoveTowards function in void update to move my robot per every frame but the problem is that he is moving only one time and stopping, he is making one step instead of for example 100. Im working with Unity3D. Here is source code;

```
public class Test01 : MonoBehaviour
{
public float speed, stopDist, rotationSpeed, moveSpeed, minSpeed, maxBackSpeed, maxFrontSpeed, turnSpeed, riseSpeed;
public Transform target;
private Rigidbody rb;
private float currentSpeed;

public bool isFinding = false;
private PlaySound signal;

void Start()
{
    signal = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Signal").GetComponent<PlaySound>();
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

private void Update()
{
    // If space key button is pressed the robot's isFinding bool is becaming true and robot is starting searching for target.
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        isFinding = true;
        if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, target.position) > stopDist)
        {
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
            signal.isAlarming = true;
            signal.Sound();
        }
        else if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, target.position) < stopDist)
        {
            isFinding = false;
            signal.isAlarming = false;
            SoundManager.instance.StopSound();
            StopChasing();
        }
    }
}
 public void StopChasing()
{
    transform.position = this.transform.position;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well currently you have everything nested under the `GetKeyDown` so it is executed only exactly **once**.

You could change that doing

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
{
    isFinding = true;
}

if(isFinding)
{
    if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, target.position) > stopDist)
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        signal.isAlarming = true;
        signal.Sound();
    }
    else
    {
        isFinding = false;
        signal.isAlarming = false;
        SoundManager.instance.StopSound();
        StopChasing();
    }
}
```

So pressing `Space` **once** activates the `isFinding` mode until it arrives at `Vector3.Distance(transform.position, target.position) < stopDist`